# Decide if matrix have rightinverse using sub-determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling finding useful information on google, so I'm asking here instead.

I want to determine if a matris $A$ of type $m \times n, m<n$ has a right inverse.
Have I understood this right that if it has a right inverse, ***all*** sub-determinants must be non-zero? So I can pick any sub-determinant and from there decide if $A$ have an inverse?

Does this also apply to left inverses?

Comment: Isn't that a bit like asking if ALL elements must be nonzero? Which of course is not true.

Comment: No. A matrix $A$ of size $m \times n$ will have a right inverse if and only if a determinant of *at least one* of its $m \times m$ submatrices is non-zero.

Comment: In practice, row-reduction tends to be a more efficient method of determining whether $A$ has a right-inverse except in some cases where $A$ has a lot of conveniently placed zero entries

Comment: @adamW That's why I'm asking. But of course there exists matrices where all elements are non zero and determinants are zero?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Okey, thanks. So the easiest why to find out if it has an inverse, lets say a matrix $A$ of type $5x3$. If I can do row reduction and manage to get 3 linearly independent vectors, I know it has a inverse - correct?

Comment: That's correct.